# Abstract class property overriding in java results in null

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, dependency-properties

I run here to a very specific Java Spring issue I can not understand.
I have created myself an abstract class, f.e:

```
public abstract class AbstractCrudServiceImpl{

    private GenericDAO baseDao;

    public GenericDAO getBaseDao() {
     return baseDao;
    } 
}
```

Generic Dao is an interface. I wanted to have the getter (and setter) in the abstract class, so the implementation would be rather simple and clear. [Does not matter if its not atm].

Then have it's implementation, for instance:

```
public class AgentServiceImpl extends AbstractCrudServiceImpl{

    @Autowired
    private AgentDao baseDao;
}
```

Using getter of superclass to run all the methods.

My intention was to have a similar effect as if I use XML like:

```
<bean id="AbstractCrudServiceImpl" class="..." abstract="true" />

<bean id="AgentServiceImpl" parent="AbstractCrudServiceImpl">
    <property name="baseDao" ref="agentDao"/>
</bean>
```

And to my surprise I got an error saying:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.insurance.central.services.impl.AbstractCrudServiceImpl.read(AbstractCrudServiceImpl.java:36)
```

which basically means, that the property is not set properly, because it's value is still null. Why!?

How should I correct it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is setting correctly the field baseDao in AgentServiceImpl. The field baseDao in parent class AbstractCrudServiceImpl stays null. In Java you can override a method, not a member variable. Try AgentServiceImpl.baseDao vs. AgentServiceImpl.super.baseDao.

Comment: So if I understand properly, there is no other way to archieve my goal, but to override the getter/setter? I thought I could delegate the getter/setter methods to parent type?

Comment: I am answering your question - you wonder why AbstractCrudServiceImpl .baseDao is null. For a proper design: a) don't use both property setter in XML and Autowired, use only annotations (aslo Component, <context:annotation-config/> etc.) b) Use @Autowired directly in the abstract class. c) remove baseDao from AbstractCrudServiceImpl.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Spring, so I can't speak to the annotations or anything, but your original property is `private`, so you can't override it. Try changing both to `protected`.

Comment: Nope, protected does not help :(

Comment: Oh, and they're also different types - the getter in the abstract class returns an instance specified only by interface, but the property you've annotated is a concrete implementation. My guess is that's tripping up the annotation processor.